# Combinatorics - schedule team associations for a game

Tags: python, combinatorics, schedule, constraint-programming

### tl;dr

I would like to distribute **players** through different **activities** of a game.
There are a fixed amount of **rounds** a team can play during the game.
The main constraints are: every **team** must plays each **game** but every **team** does **not** have to play against **all the teams**.

I haved searched for answers on the web but they are all related to tournaments, which does not have the same constraints as I do.

You can now skip the two next sections.

### Introduction

I am part of the organization of a huge game and I have the responsibility to distribute the players through the different activities during the game. When I realized it was not an easy problem to solve, I tried to code a Python script to do the job. Then, I realized I was doing it wrong because my script worked in a deterministic way. People told me I should do it with a solver (Constraint Programming). However I had no notions in this field. It tried to use the package [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) to solve my problem but I did not succeed in defining the good constraints.

### Searches I have done

I have also searched on the web about this problem but most of the answers I found are related to tournaments, which does not have the same constraints as I do. Indeed, the main goal of a tournament is to be sure each team plays against all the other teams. Here, the main constraint is to be sure every team plays at every activities.
I found [a similar thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486029/teams-in-tournament-problem) on math.stackexchange but the constraints were not the same and there were no proper answer to the problem.

### The inputs

- There are **36 teams**.
- There are **22 activities**. (there are duels)
- There are **22 rounds**.

### The constraints

1. A team cannot play **against itself**.
2. Each team must play at **every activity**.
3. A team cannot do more than **22 activities** during the game. (since there are only 22 rounds)
4. **Minimize** teams playing against a team they already have played with.

Since there are 36 teams for 22 duels, some activities will be empty at every round.
Since there are 22 activities and 22 rounds, a team cannot do an activity more than once.

### Example of a likely answer

```
       | Round 1        | Round 2        | Round n        
------ | -------------- | -------------- | --------------  
Game 1 | Team1 vs Team2 | Team3 vs Team5 | Team? vs Team?  
Game 2 | Team3 vs Team4 | Team1 vs Team6 | Team? vs Team?  
Game n | Team? vs Team? | Team? vs Team? | Team? vs Team?
```

### Model of the problem in Python

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("Activity", [i for i in range(1, 22+1)])
problem.addVariables(["Team1", "Team2"], [i for i in range(1, 36+1)])
problem.addVariable("Round", [i for i in range(1, 22+1)])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a != b, ("Team1", "Team2"))
???
```

### My question

I am looking for someone who could either:

- define what **constraints** I should use for my problem.
- or resolve this problem with **combinatorics**.

It could be in any language or with any tool. I used Python as an example.

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here are some examples wrt tennis games: [model1](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/tennis-scheduling.html), [model2](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/more-tennis-scheduling.html), [model3](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/more-tennis-scheduling.html). Not the same as your example, but close. The models are not completely trivial, but I believe it often helps to first write down a mathematical model.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not trivial at all, but I'll try to approach it.:) I'll try to **define** the problem in terms of constraint satisfiability. I'll rely on [Boolean satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) and use [Tseitin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) to encode your task.

First of all, let's introduce a set of Boolean variables that corresponds to a game that was played by a team during a round:

> game0_team0_round0, g0_t0_r1, ..., gk_tm_rn

We are going to encode constraints as a Boolean formula. It returns **True** iff there is such a schedule that satisfies all given constraints. An set of values for variables defined above represents a schedule: if variable equals **True** then a game was played by corresponding team within corresponding round. We introduce a lot of constraints. Let's agree that if a constraint formula returns **True** then this constraint is violated.

First constraint prohibits a team from playing **several** games within a round:

```
for round in rounds:
    for team in teams:
        games = get_games_from_team_and_round (round, team)
        constr = greater_then_equal (games, 2)
        add_must_be_false_constr (constr)
```

'greater_then_equal' builds *pseudo-boolean* constraints that ensures that only one game can be **True** for team/round. You can read [here](http://minisat.se/downloads/MiniSat+.pdf) how to implement it. 'add_must_be_false_constr' ensures that a constraint won't be violated.

Next, let's introduce *dueling* constraint: within a round, two teams must be playing. At the same time, they have to play the same game:

```
for round in rounds:
    for game in games:
        teams = get_teams_from_round (round)
        constr = greater_then_equal (teams, 3)
        add_must_be_false_constr (constr)
```

Finally, each team must play each game:

```
for round in rounds:
    for team in teams:
        games = get_games_from_team_and_round (round, team)
        constr = boolean_or (games)
        add_must_be_false_constr (constr)
```

We ensure that at least one game will be played each round.

You can put resulting formula into a solver (e.g. [Glucose](http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/)), it will find you **random** schedule that satisfies all given constraints.

Now the tricky part - minimization. I'm not sure how to do it properly, but, for example, you can introduce a variable that is **True** if a pair of teams played a game during a given round. Next, you are introducing 'greater_then_equal' constraint to limit a number of **True** values for these variables. Finally, you can use [assumptions](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/slides/SAT2013-audemard.pdf) to find the best schedule with minimal repetitions.

Be aware that with this approach it might take a lot of time to solve a task: it's not trivial to implement everything in a proper way, so that's why I do not provide your with code, but just give you a pretty generic description how to do it. Solving a problem might take up to several hours, but it depends on the problem itself and constraints. Other issue - it might consume a lot of memory. I have practical experience with solving **very big** (10^4 variables, 10^6 constraints) problems by doing similar stuff. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I finally found a way to do it manually but I still plan to make a software tool for the future editions. I'll try to do it your way then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in [MiniZinc](http://minizinc.org). Here are the basic ideas:

1) The decision variables to handle which teams will play when is the 3 dimensional array `x` of size number of activities x number of rounds x 2 and contains the two teams which are play at a specific activity and round. Since there might be "null" games, i.e. a round/activity when no team play the domain is 0..number of teams, where "team" 0 indicate a null game. We also  add the constraint that if one team of a play is team 0 then the other team must also be team 0: `(x[a,r,1] = 0 <-> x[a,r,2] = 0)` where `<->` indicates implication.

2) For the constraints that all teams must participate in all activities and all rounds, only two (global) constraints are needed: `global_cardinality` which counts the number of times a team is participating in the activities and the rounds, respectively.

3) The objective of the problem is to minimize the number of "double" plays between the teams. For this the 2 dimensional matrix `y` is used: it contains the number of matches two teams plays each other. The model objective `z` counts the number of double plays, which we then minimize. However, it seems that there is no need to be any double plays at all, and hence the domain of `y` is just 0..1, i.e. either two teams play meet each other once or not at all. Since the domain is 1 this actually constrain the model to not allow any double plays at all. Note: I don't know if this works for all different values of the number of teams x activities x rounds, but it works for the different instances I've tested, including the 32 x 22 x 22 instance in the question.

```
include "globals.mzn"; 
int: num_teams = 36;
int: num_activities = 22;
int: num_rounds = 22;

% decision variables
%  x[a,r,1..2] = t1..t2: team t1 and team t2 plays in activity a, round r
% 0 mean an empty game
array[1..num_activities, 1..num_rounds, 1..2] of var 0..num_teams: x;

% number of plays against the other teams
array[1..num_teams, 1..num_teams] of  var 0..1: y;
% number of plays where a team meet another team more than once
var 0..(num_teams*(num_teams-1)) div 2: z; %  = sum([y[t1,t2] > 1 | t1,t2 in 1..num_teams where t1 < t2]);

% minimize the number of "double" matches between the teams
solve :: int_search(array1d(x), most_constrained, indomain_min, complete) minimize z;

constraint
    % the number of times the teams play against each other
    forall(t1 in 1..num_teams) ( 
        y[t1,t1] = 0 % a team do not play against itself
        /\
        forall(t2 in 1..num_teams where t1 < t2) (
             y[t1,t2] = sum([x[a,r,1] = t1 /\ x[a,r,2] = t2 | a in 1..num_activities, r in 1..num_rounds])
             /\
             y[t2,t1] = y[t1,t2] % symmetric matrix
        )
    )
    /\
    z = sum([y[t1,t2] > 1 | t1,t2 in 1..num_teams where t1 < t2])

    % /\ z = 0
    ;

    constraint
       % a team must participate in all activities
       forall(a in 1..num_activities) (
          global_cardinality([x[a,r,i] | r in 1..num_rounds, i in 1..2],1..num_teams,[1 | r in 1..num_teams]) :: domain
      )

      /\ % a team must participate in all rounds
      forall(r in 1..num_rounds) (
            global_cardinality([x[a,r,i] | a in 1..num_activities, i in 1..2],1..num_teams,[1 | r in 1..num_teams]) :: domain
      )

      /\ % null games "team" 0 vs "team" 0
      forall(a in 1..num_activities,r in 1..num_rounds) (
          (x[a,r,1] = 0 <-> x[a,r,2] = 0)
       )
       ;

       output 
       [ "z:\(z)\n" ] ++
       [
         if r = 1 then "\n" else "" endif ++
            "\(a)-\(r): \(x[a,r,1]) vs \(x[a,r,2])\n"
         | a in 1..num_activities, r in 1..num_rounds
       ]
       ++
       [ % the play matrix
          if t2 = 1 then "\n" else "" endif ++
            show_int(2,y[t1,t2]) ++ " "
          | t1,t2 in 1..num_teams
       ]
       ++ [ "\n\nz:\(z)\n" ];
```

The Gecode solver solves the problem in 8s (and the time for creating the FlatZinc model takes about a minute). For the smaller problem 18 teams x 11 activities x 11 rounds, it take 4s (including flattening to FlatZinc).

The model is also here: http://hakank.org/minizinc/schedule_team_associations_for_a_game.mzn . It includes some commented stuff I tested, e.g. different symmetry breaking constraints, but this quite down scaled model seems to be the fastest. The order of the teams in an activity and round in the solution seems to be random. If that's a problem some symmetry breaking constraints will help (but it might take a longer time to solve).

The solution is too long to show here, but is saved in http://hakank.org/minizinc/schedule_team_associations_for_a_game.txt

Also, as it stands the model is a minimization problem and will only show one solution. If more/many solutions are wanted, just two changes are needed:

1) Change the `solve ... minimize z` to `solve satisfy`.

2) Uncomment the line `z = 0`.